# How to get ROW id from dynamic ajax generated table (PHP, JQuery, MySQL)

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, ajax

Okay so I have been working on this small project, I have done this before; using jquery when clicking on table row gives an ID/value, but not with php or ajax. So I'm kinda lost, before the ajax query the table has a preset row with information in it. When I click on it everything works fine, but after selecting a source from the drop down menu (the source is a name to search for all rows containing a certain name) and it load all related rows into the table. Clicking on a row jquery does nothing on the generated data, but when clicking on the thead it launches the test alert I have set up. I am using HotKeys to open hidden popup windows for the user to interact with the form/page.

`jquery-1.7.1.js.js`
`jqueryhotkeys.js`
**External JS File**:`eval.js`

```
var s,
    Joe = {
        settings: {                 
        winWidth:       $(window).width(),
        winHeight:      $(window).height(),
        entriesPopW:    $('#overlay_entries').width(),
        entriesPopH:    $('#overlay_entries').height()
    },
    init: function() {
        s = this.settings;
        this.bindUIActions();
    },
    bindUIActions: function() {                 
        $(document).bind('keydown.f7',function (evt){
            //View Previous Entries
            $("#overlay_entries").fadeIn(1000);Joe.entries();Joe.loadEntries();
            $("#assList").change(function(e){
                assSelect = $("#assList").val();
                Joe.entryTable(assSelect);
            });
            $("#table-2 tr").click(function() {
                alert("You clicked ROW:\n\nID:  " + $(this).attr('id'));
            });
            $(".f7button").click(function(x){$("#overlay_entries").fadeOut(500);return false;});
            return false; 
        });             
    },
    //shows or hides hidden window
    entries: function(){if(!$("#overlay_entries").is(':visible')){return;} $("#overlay_entries").css({  left: (s.entriesPopW/2)+50 ,top: (s.entriesPopH/2)+50,position:'fixed'   }); },
    //populates table after drop down menu selection
    entryTable: function(a){
        var jac = a;
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "joe_functions.php?select="+jac,
            error: function() {alert('error');},
            success: function (data) {
                $("#table-2 tbody").ajaxComplete(function () {
                    $(this).html(data);                    
                });
            }
        }); 
    },
    //this loads the dropdown menu with names
    loadEntries: function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "joe_functions.php?content=dropdown",
            error: function() {alert('error');},
            success: function (data) {$("#assList").ajaxComplete(function () {$(this).html(data);});}
        });
    }
};
```

**HTML File**

```
<head>
    <title>The Eval Form</title>
    <script src="jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.hotkeys.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="eval.js"></script>
    <script>
        (function() {Joe.init();})();
    </script>
<style>
</style>

</head>

<body>
<div id="overlay_entries" style="display:none">
    <h2> Previous Entries:</h2>
    <center>
        <select name="" id="assList"></select><br/><br/>    
        <table id="table-2">
            <thead>
                <th class="entryColOne">Associate</th>
                <th class="entryColTwo">Eval Date</th>
                <th class="entryColThree">Score</th>
                <th class="entryColFour">Overall</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>John</td>
                    <td>Smith</td>
                    <td>johnsmith@example.com</td>
                    <td>http://www.example.com</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <br/>
        <input type="submit" class="f7button" value=""/>
    </center>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**PHP File:** `joe_functions.php`

```
<?php
require 'db_connect.php';

if(isset($_GET['select']) && !empty($_GET['select'])){
    $passed = $_GET['select'];
    //$test = '<tr><td colspan=4">'.$passed.'</td></tr>';
    $sqlb   = 'SELECT * FROM joe_eval WHERE wmid ='.$passed.' ORDER BY id';
    $queryb     = mysql_query($sqlb);
    $numb   = mysql_num_rows($queryb);

    $tableData = '';
    $ib = 0;
    if(!$queryb){
        $query_error = '<tr><td colspan="4">MySQL Error: '.mysql_error().'</td></tr>';
        $tableData .= $query_error;
    }else{
        while($ib <$numb){
            $wmid   = mysql_result($queryb,$ib,'wmid');
            $person     = mysql_result($queryb,$ib,'employee'); 
            $id = mysql_result($queryb,$ib,'id');
            $date       = mysql_result($queryb,$ib,'date');
            $score      = (mysql_result($queryb,$ib,'dm1')+mysql_result($queryb,$ib,'dm2')+mysql_result($queryb,$ib,'dm3')+mysql_result($queryb,$ib,'dm4')+mysql_result($queryb,$ib,'dm5')+mysql_result($queryb,$ib,'dm6')+mysql_result($queryb,$ib,'dm7'))/7;
            $numFormat = number_format($score, 2, '.', '');
            $overall    =   '';

            if ($numFormat >= 1 && $numFormat < 1.6) {$overall = 'Below Needs';
            }else if ($numFormat >= 1.6 && $numFormat < 2.7) {$overall = 'Improvment Needed';
            }else if ($numFormat >= 2.7 && $numFormat < 3.6) {$overall = 'Good Performer';
            }else if ($numFormat >= 3.6 && $numFormat < 4.6) {$overall = 'Exceeds Expectations';
            }else if ($numFormat >= 4.6 && $numFormat <= 5) {$overall = 'Top Dog';}

                // HERE IS WERE THE ROW ID IS BEING INSERTED
                // WHICH WILL LATER BE USED TO LOAD FORM
                $tableData .= '<tr id="'.$id.'"><td>'.$person.'</td><td>'.$date.'</td><td class="score">'.$numFormat.'</td><td>'.$overall.'</td></tr>';
            $ib++;
        }
    }
    // Send back the tbody HTM
    echo $tableData;
}else{
    $tableData .= '<tr><td colspan="4"><b>YOU MUST SELECT A NAME FROM THE LIST ABOVE!</b></td></tr>';
}
?>
```

So I'm not sure if it might be an error in the JS file, or if I should be adding something in the PHP file to generated along with the data that's sent to the ajax request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to **Mandeep Jain** for the tap on the shoulder to look in a different direction, this was a quick and easy fix.

#### First Try:

```
$("#table-2 tbody tr").click(function() {
     alert("You clicked ROW:\n\nID:  " + $(this).attr('id'));
});
```

#### Second Try:

```
$("#table-2 tbody tr").on("click", function() {
     alert("You clicked ROW:\n\nID:  " + $(this).attr('id'));
});
```

#### Third and Final WORKING Fix:

```
$("#table-2 tbody tr").live("click", function() {
     alert("You clicked ROW:\n\nID:  " + $(this).attr('id'));
});
```

[JQuery Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/live/):

> As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to
>   attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use
>   .delegate() in preference to .live().
>
> This method provides a means to attach delegated event handlers to the
>   document element of a page, which simplifies the use of event handlers
>   when content is dynamically added to a page.

Comment: as it is mentioned, why are you using live() when it is deprecated ?
live has been replaced by on

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is use jquery .on(), which is used to bind event handlers on dynamically generated data, in your case the data received from ajax call,

So instead of

```
$("#table-2 tr").click(function() {
      alert("You clicked ROW:\n\nID:  " + $(this).attr('id'));
});
```

you could do something like this

```
$("#table-2 tr").on("click", function() {
      alert("You clicked ROW:\n\nID:  " + $(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Let me know if that helps.

You can also read about jquery .on() [here](http://api.jquery.com/on)

Comment: nope didn't work,,, but going to try live and see if that might work. thanks for the reply though

Comment: live is deprecated, live has been replaced by on, and removed from 1.9

Comment: i'm using 1.7.1 for this project when i tried to use the Hot Keys addon with 1.9 it wouldn't work so i stuck with the version they included with their file

Comment: but i cant still see why .on() doesnt work for u. It was added in version 1.7

Comment: dunno when i tried .on() it wouldn't fire the alert after the dynamic loaded rows were inserted. It does work on the default row before replacing